# Como acedo a otro proyecto creado anteriormente convertido en .jar y lo inicializo?

Tags: java

El ejercicio es el siguiente:
Crearemos un programa llamado *Aleatorio* que generará números aleatorios según le pasemos por parámetros de entrada, por ejemplo entre 10 y 500.

Mostrará por salida estándar línea a línea cada uno de los números generados hasta que lo cerremos. Compilaremos y crearemos el ejecutable *Aleatorios.jar*

Crearemos otro programa Java llamado *Principal*, que lanzará como proceso el programa anterior con los respectivos parámetros de entrada durante un segundo (`Thread.sleep(10000);`) y lo destruirá. Irá recogiendo la salida de este programa y almacenándola en un ArrayList. Posteriormente mostrará dicho `ArrayList` de números generados tal y posteriormente ordenados por el método que prefieras.

La primera parte la tengo

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("introduce el primer numero");
        int num1 = entrada.nextInt();
        System.out.println("introduce el segundo numero");
        int num2 = entrada.nextInt();
        boolean parar = false;
         while (!parar) {
            int available;
            double resultado;
            while ((available = System.in.available()) == 0) {
                if (num1 > num2) {
                    resultado = Math.random() * (num1 - num2) + num2;
                } else {
                    resultado = Math.random() * (num2 - num1) + num1;
                }
                System.out.println(""+resultado);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

La 2ª parte de acceder al programa ya no tengo ni idea

Comment: Investiga sobre el Process API.

Answer (score 2):

Estimado, en este portal no se resuelven tareas, y debes ser mas claro para formular tu pregunta !
No tengo la solución exacta para tu problema pero si algunas observaciones:

- Cuando hablamos de parámetros de entrada, generalmente son aquellos que se pasan por línea de comandos al ejectuar tu código, por lo que debes leer esos parámetros desde la variable `args[]` y pasarlos al momento de ejecutar de la forma: `$java aleatorio.jar param1 param2`.
- El ciclo `while(!parar)` es infinito, lo cual no es buena práctica. Si quieres detenerlo por teclado en la consola usando *CTRL + C* sería bueno que uses un bloque `try`/`catch` para la excepción de interrupción por teclado (Una buena y simple explicación: http://www.sc.ehu.es/sbweb/fisica/cursoJava/fundamentos/excepciones/excepciones.htm)
- Sería bueno que indiques si manejan el paradigma de Orientación a Objetos, ya que el problema que planteas se soluciona creando la clase `Aleatorio` con las funciones que indican y llamandola desde una clase `main`.

Comment: Solo he realizado lo que me piden. y tal como me lo piden